# Is there any built-in behavior for Command + Delete (delete line right of cursor) in macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

It is possible to press <kbd>⎇ Backspace</kbd> on macOS in order to delete the previous word (left of the cursor), and <kbd>⌘ Backspace</kbd> to delete the previous line (left of the cursor). If you have an external keyboard with a "delete" key (or the "forward delete key"), or are able to emulate the delete key via software, it is possible to press <kbd>⎇ Delete</kbd> to delete the word to the right of the cursor. However, perhaps surprisingly, it is not possible to press <kbd>⌘ Delete</kbd> in order to delete the line to the right of the cursor.

Now, I have only been able to make this possible by emulating a <kbd>⌘⇧→</kbd> and then a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> with BetterTouchTool. However, I want to avoid doing something like this because BTT does not work at a "low enough level" for me – that is to say, the action is not entirely reliable.

Is there any official macOS way to delete the line to the right of the cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, macOS Supports Emacs style shortcuts...

What you are looking for is this: <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Technically by holding the <kbd>fn</kbd> button with the backspace you get the actual <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, but on my mac at least it doesn't allow forward delete to the end of the line, but the above shortcut does.

This should work but doesn't:
<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

However you've got an answer now...

*Source: [Apple Questions](https://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/readonly/the-one-delete-key-moves-left-is-there-a-single-keystroke-way-to-delete-right-with-this-keyboard/QKTDPPDJD9XPFFUTA)*